# Probability help! Am i wrong?

Tags: probability

So here is the summary for the question: 100 women use a new pregnancy test, 44 of the women are actually pregnant.  Of the women who are pregnant, 35 test positive.  Of the women who are not pregnant, 8 of them test positive.  Calculate the probability for each event.

Did I get this question right? Here is the question: A randomly selected test is negative, given the woman is not pregnant.

I got: $P(\text{Negative|Not Pregnant})
= \frac{56}{66} = 0.85$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enough data to make a complete cross-tabulation:

$$\begin{array}{r|c|c|c}
&\text{pos.}&\text{neg.}&\text{total}\\ \hline
\text{pregnant}&35&9&44\\ \hline
\text{not pregnant}&8&48&56\\ \hline
\text{total}&43&57&100
\end{array}$$

There are $56$ women who are not pregnant, and $48$ of them test negative, so the probability that a randomly chosen non-pregnant woman tests negative is

$$\frac{48}{56}=\frac67=0.\overline{857142}\;.$$

This is slightly larger than your $\frac{56}{66}=\frac{28}{33}=0.\overline{84}$.

Comment: @PittzBurgh: You’re welcome; glad it helped!

Comment: How about this question?: A randomly selected test is positive
P(Positive)
= (0.44*0.80)+(0.66*0.12)
= 0.35 + 0.08 
= 0.43 (My answer, is this correct?)

Comment: @PittzBurgh: Yes, it is, but you can get it more directly from the bottom line of the table: there are $43$ positive tests out the $100$ total.

Comment: Lastly, one last question to verify my answers, your the best. So here is the question: A randomly selected test is from a woman who is pregnant given it is negative. I got Neg= (0.44*0.2)+(0.66*0.857) = 0.65. Is this correct!?

Comment: @PittzBurgh: No, that’s way too large. There are $57$ negative tests, and $9$ of them are from a pregnant woman, so the desired probability is $\frac9{57}=\frac3{19}$, which is a little less than $0.16$.

Comment: I forgot to verify ONE more answer, this is the question: A Randomly Selected Test is Incorrect (False-positive) or false-negative). I got (0.44*0.2)+(0.66*0.12) = 0.17. Is this finally correct???

Comment: Thank you for everything now I learn my mistakes!

Comment: @PittzBurgh: Yes, that’s right: we have $9$ false negatives and $8$ false positives for a total of $17$ erroneous results out of $100$. You’re welcome!

Comment: Can you please verify my other question I posted.  If not its cool :-) You just seem really informational

Comment: @PittzBurgh: Sorry, which question is that?